# Maximum of minimum number of moves required for hardest 8 puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, searching

I have read that the hardest 8 puzzle requires 31 steps to solve, i.e. every solvable 8 puzzle can be solved in max. 31 steps. How is that?

Comment: What the heck is an "8 puzzle"????

Comment: It's a variant of 15 puzzle for 3*3 Board

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle

Comment: What do you mean by 'how is that' here? How did they find that number? How is it not smaller? How would you compute the number for a larger puzzle?

Comment: How did they find that number?

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia link for the [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) points to an [OEIS link](http://oeis.org/A087725) which points to a paper "[Complete Solution of the Eight-Puzzle ..](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.9889)" by Alexander Reinefeld. (The link in the OIES page is bad.) The distribution of solution lengths and the maximum length 31 were obtained by exhaustively evaluating all $9!/2$ configurations.